# Standard deviation of a joint probability distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, standard-deviation

I have the joint distribution. This is how many packages of toilet paper, $\mathbf{T}$, and packages of wipes, $\mathbf{W}$, a shopper can obtain per visit.

[image: T: Toilet paper, W: wipes]

I'm being tasked to find the standard deviation of the packages of wipes purchased, given that a shopper has bought exactly one package of toilet paper.

This is my current work. I found the conditional expectation to act as my $E[X]$, as well as applied the same idea for $E[X^2]$. I used these values to find $Var(X)$, and then square rooted for the standard deviation.

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
E[W]=E[W|T=1] &= \sum_{i=1}^m a_i\cdot P(W|T=1)\\
&= 0\cdot .22 + 1\cdot .05 + 2\cdot .03\\
E[W] &= .11
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
E[W^2]=E[W^2|T=1] &= \sum_{i=1}^m a_i\cdot P(W^2|T=1)\\
&= 0^2\cdot .22 + 1^2\cdot .05 + 2^2\cdot .03\\
E[W^2] &= .17
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Now,

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
Var(W) & = E[W^2] - E[W]^2\\
&= .17 - .11^2\\
Var(W) &= .1597
\end{split}
\end{equation}

By this logic, my standard deviation should be $\sigma = \sqrt{Var(W)} = \boxed{.3973}$. My answer key however says $\sigma = .6574$

Comment: Your approach seems wrong. You need to find the marginal distribution, which are the row/column sums. For instance, the marginal distribution of $W$ is obtained by summing the columns row-wise, so that $P(W = 0) = 0.31+0.22+0.09+0.04 = 0.73,$ etc. Then you can find the standard deviation in the usual way $\sqrt{\mathbf{V}(W)} = \sqrt{\mathbf{E}(W^2) - \mathbf{E}(W)^2}.$

Comment: Your calculation is *almost* correct -- but the values you used for $P(W=w|T=1)$ are wrong: Instead of using the values in the table (which are $P(W=w \text{ and }T=1),$ you need to use $P(W=w\mid T=1)=P(W=w \text{ and }T=1)/P(T=1)$. In other words, the probabilities in the $T=1$ column each need to be divided by the sum of that column.